# How to put view below a textview which has dynamic text

Tags: android, android-layout

I have recently started learning android. I am creating a layout which is something like

[image: Layout]

In the image: which i click on **Button** ,**Text** will get populated with some value
And then i want the position of 2nd **Text** to be dynamically adjusted.

Currently both gets overlapped.

My XML file is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="2.5" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/get_address_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="getAddress"
        android:text="@string/get_address" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/get_address_button"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:text="@string/address"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/address_progress"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/label_address"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/label_address"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/label_address"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_distance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/label_address"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:text="@string/distance"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/location_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/label_distance"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/label_distance"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help.

Thanks

Comment: Post your Layout Code

Comment: Added XML file in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this layout

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/get_address_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="getAddress"
        android:text="getAddress" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/get_address_button" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label_address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
            android:text="Address 
        this is line 1
        this is line 2
        this is line 3
        "
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/label_address"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/label_address"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/address_progress"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/label_address"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_distance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/get_address_button"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:text="Distance"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/location_spinner"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Result is still same. Initially everything looks fine but as soon as first text field gets populated with multi line text it gets overlapped with spinner/text below

Comment: How do you want your layout to be ? what if there are say 20 lines then your spinner should set at the bottom right?

Comment: Yes it should be below the lines be it 1 line or 20. Thanks

Comment: Brontok, Thanks it actually works after little modification. Will accept it

Answer (score 0):

Do it with `RelativeLayout`, and the atribute `android:below="@+id/idofyourmultilineedittext"`
hope it helps

Comment: Still my last block gets overlapped with the text

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure where you want to position it,but if you want to position your 2nd text to the left/right/bottom/top  then you can do something like this

1) take reference of  your second Text View and and use
 **yourTextView.setGravity(GRAVITY.LEFT/RIGHT/TOP/BOTTOM)**

Comment: Still my last block gets overlapped with the text